# Mamp PHP blank page

Tags: php, mamp

i have installed mamp on my mac everything was fine my project was added correctly and most of my pages worked normally. 
But one of my page ( writted in php) was in blank and i don't know why. sorry for my english btw ,
thanks for your help .

Comment: i'm going to see thanks

Comment: /Applications/MAMP/conf/php7.4.1/php.ini they talking of this file because the indications they give are quite different of the current file ...

Comment: I unfortunately wouldn't be able to tell you, I fortunately haven't worked on OS X for many years now